# Ubuntu Cannot Assign Static on IP Multiple Interface (RTNETLINK answers: File exists)

Tags: networking, server

I've installed Ubuntu 16.04 server edition to my machine. I have 4 ethernet interfaces and I want to assign static IP to all of those.

I have read some questions and answer and applied them such as removing gateway from eno2-3-4 since its avaliable on eno1 but no luck

**My config looks like below;**

```
# The primary network interface
auto eno1
iface eno1 inet static
address 10.***.***.174
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 10.***.***.1
dns-nameservers 208.67.220.220 208.67.222.222

# The secondary network interface
auto eno2
iface eno2 inet static
address 10.***.***.175
netmask 255.255.255.0
dns-nameservers 208.67.220.220 208.67.222.222

# The tertiary network interface
auto eno3
iface eno3 inet static
address 10.***.***.176
netmask 255.255.255.0
dns-nameservers 208.67.220.220 208.67.222.222

# The quaternary network interface
auto eno4
iface eno4 inet static
address 10.***.***.177
netmask 255.255.255.0
dns-nameservers 208.67.220.220 208.67.222.222
```

**When I check the error log, I get these errors below**

```
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Failed to bring up eno1.
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Failed to bring up eno2.
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Failed to bring up eno3.
```

I have tried to flush ip addresses and devices, tried to reboot the machine but still no luck. When I try to `systemctl restart (or start) networking.service` I get these errors above.

Is there any other file do I have to update?

Comment: Did you try to also remove the dns-nameservers from eno2-3-4 ? I guess they might all try to write in the same resolv.conf

Comment: @derHugo I found the solution by chance, the indentation was the problem for some reason

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by chance. Interestingly I changed the **indentation** to below, the service started immediately without any errors..

```
# The primary network interface
auto eno1
iface eno1 inet static
    address 10.***.***.174
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 10.***.***.1
    dns-nameservers 208.67.220.220 208.67.222.222

# The secondary network interface
auto eno2
iface eno2 inet static
    address 10.***.***.175
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    dns-nameservers 208.67.220.220 208.67.222.222

# The tertiary network interface
auto eno3
iface eno3 inet static
    address 10.***.***.176
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    dns-nameservers 208.67.220.220 208.67.222.222

# The quaternary network interface
auto eno4
iface eno4 inet static
    address 10.***.***.177
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    dns-nameservers 208.67.220.220 208.67.222.222
```

Comment: haha I thought you just copied them wrong to your question ^^
But yes it always has to be a tab

Comment: @derHugo Newbie problems.. :-) By the way, I have those DNS IP's in my `resolv.conf` file, is it okay to remove them in my interfaces or any benefits keeping them?

Comment: I don't know exactly because I even thought it is not allowed to have multible interfaces on the same network running because anyway the OS will allways automatically decide for one and only use that one. So I would expect that since it will use interface eno1 as Gateway because it has the gateway configured it would also be enough to have dns-nameservs also only on that one configured. Is there a reason why you gave them all IPs on the same network?